# Print the console results inside a textbox (two file py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In a Tkinter window of the Test.py file, I would like to display in a textobox what is printed in the Python console.

By clicking on button, you start a function in the Test.py file that calls the X.py and Y.py scripts (more precisely their functions). The results of the scripts are printed correctly in the Python console: first the result of the X file is printed and then immediately after the result of the Y file is printed.

I would like to see these X.py and Y.py results printed in a textbox. Of course, if possible, I would also like to hide (not open at all) the Python console. I have read a few questions here on the site, but have not been able to accomplish this. Above for information purposes I have explained the purpose of what I am creating, therefore it is useless to paste the entire code already working of the various functions. Can you help me and show me the code to view the script results in the textobox please?

Of course, if possible, I would also like to hide (not open at all) the Python console

```
#IMPORT OF FILE X AND Y, AND RELATED FUNCTIONS
from File.X import Example_Name_Function_1
from File.Y import Example_Name_Function_2

#TEXTOBOX
text = tk.Text(test,width=80,height=50,  background="black", foreground="white")
text.pack()
text.place(x=450, y=20)
text.insert(INSERT, "aaaaaaaa\n")
text.insert(END, " bbbbbbbb \n")

#BUTTON
button = Button(test, text="Go", foreground='black', command= Go)
button.place(x=7, y=512)
```

**CODE UPDATE**

I have reported the initial code. Now the window opens immediately and the scraping starts only after clicking on the button. As a result, the results of the scraping are printed in the Python terminal console. Not in the textobox. Being long in the code, I preferred to report it like this. But inside the code of @Matiiss, but it doesn't work

```
#I open tkinter window for scraping
editmenu.add_command(label='Scraping', command=filename.draw_graph)
```

_

```
#WINDOW SCRAPING
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

from File import Scraping_Nome_Campionati
from File import Scraping_Nome_Squadre_MIO

import subprocess


def draw_graph():
    test_scraping=tk.Toplevel()
    test_scraping.title("Scraping")
    test_scraping.geometry("1100x900")
    test_scraping.configure(bg='#282828')


    #I call up and open the two scripts for scraping (no tkinter)
    def do_scraping():
    
        msg1 = Scraping_Nome_Campionati.scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor()
        if msg1:
            message1.configure(text=msg1)
            message1.configure(foreground="red")
            vuoto_elenco_campionati.config(image=render7)
        
        else:
            vuoto_elenco_campionati.config(image=render8)
            message1.configure(foreground="green")


        msg2 = Scraping_Nome_Squadre_MIO.scraping_nome_squadre_e_tor()
        if msg2:
            message2.configure(text=msg2)
            message2.configure(foreground="red")
            vuoto_elenco_squadre.config(image=render7)

        else:
            vuoto_elenco_squadre.config(image=render8)
            message2.configure(foreground="green")


    #YOUR CODE
    def call_obj_from(obj, module):
        if module:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-c', f'from {module} import {obj}; {obj}()'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            return proc.communicate()[0].decode()


        text.insert('end', call_obj_from('scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor', 'File.Scraping_Nome_Campionati'))
        text.insert('end', call_obj_from('scraping_nome_squadre_e_tor', 'file.Scraping_Nome_Squadre_MIO'))  

    text = tk.Text(test_scraping,width=80,height=50,  background="black", foreground="white")
    text.pack()
    text.place(x=450, y=20)

    text.insert(INSERT, "aaaaaa\n")
    text.insert(END, "bbbbbbbbb\n")


    button = Button(test_scraping, text="Avvia", bg='#e95420', foreground='white', command=do_scraping)
    button.place(x=116, y=512)

    test_scraping.mainloop()
```

**CODE UPLOAD 2**

```
# Text widget with file-like object feature
class TextOut(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

    # required output function for a file-like object
    def write(self, message):
        self.insert("insert", message)



def do_scraping():

        # temporarily redirect sys.stdout
    with redirect_stdout(text) as f:
        scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor()
        scraping_nome_squadre_e_tor()
        print("completed") # this shows in the text box as well
    print("done") # this will show in console instead of text box
    

    msg1 = Scraping_Nome_Campionati.scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor()
    if msg1:
        message1.configure(text=msg1)
        message1.configure(foreground="red")
        vuoto_elenco_campionati.config(image=render7)
        
    else:
        vuoto_elenco_campionati.config(image=render8)
        message1.configure(foreground="green")


    msg2 = Scraping_Nome_Squadre_MIO.scraping_nome_squadre_e_tor()
    if msg2:
        message2.configure(text=msg2)
        message2.configure(foreground="red")
        vuoto_elenco_squadre.config(image=render7)

    else:
        vuoto_elenco_squadre.config(image=render8)
        message2.configure(foreground="green")


text = TextOut(test_scraping,width=80,height=50,  background="black", foreground="white")
text.pack()
text.place(x=450, y=20)


button = Button(test_scraping, text="Avvia", bg='#e95420', foreground='white', command=do_scraping)
button.place(x=116, y=512)
```

Comment: could use `subprocess` module to get the output of those functions and then insert them to the text widget

Comment: @matiiss Yes. I used import subprocess as sub and then also from subprocess import Popen, PIPE. I couldn't get it all to work. So I deleted everything. I made a mess. Could you help me by showing me the code please? Thank you

Comment: if you create class with method `write(text)` which send text to `Text` and you assign to `sys.stdout` then all `print()` in current code will send text to `Text`. This was described few times on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `pack()`, `grid()` and `place()` are different `layout managers` - if you use `place()` then you don't need `pack()`

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.4+, you can use `contextlib.redirect_stdout` (see [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)) to redirect `sys.stdout` to another file or file-like object temporarily.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from File.X import Example_Name_Function_1
from File.Y import Example_Name_Function_2

# Text widget with file-like object feature
class TextOut(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

    # required output function for a file-like object
    def write(self, message):
        self.insert("insert", message)


def Go():
    # temporarily redirect sys.stdout
    with redirect_stdout(text) as f:
        Example_Name_Function_1()
        Example_Name_Function_2()
        print("completed") # this shows in the text box as well
    print("done") # this will show in console instead of text box

test = tk.Tk()

# use TextOut instead of normal Text widget
text = TextOut(test, width=80, height=50, bg="black", fg="white")
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(test, text="Go", command=Go)
button.pack()

test.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get `completed` in `Text` even without `file=f` - simply `print("completed")`

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you very much. Being new to Python, I have never used self in code, but I have seen many use it. What is it for? Can you write the code even without self? If so, could you please delete those selves (or replace them?)? Forgive the request. Thank you

Comment: @furas Yes, `file=f` is optional because `print()` is within the `with` block.

Comment: @JamesD.Com you may define `def write(message): text.insert("insert", message)` and assing `sys.stdout.write = write` and then it will print to `Text` without using class (which needs `self.`) You could even reduce it to `sys.stdout.write = lambda message: text.insert("insert", message)` But it could be good to kee original `write` to assign it back later `origina_write = sys.stdout.write`, `...code...`, `sys.stdout.write = origina_write`

Comment: @JamesD.Com Using `contextlib.redirect_stdout` requires a *file or file-like object*, so using class (what you said the `self` stuff) is easier (and I think is better) than using normal functions.

Comment: @acw1668 Ah OK. However how can I delete text.insert (INSERT, "aaaaaaaa \ n") and text.insert (END, "bbbbbbbb \ n") in the textbox, when it displays the console results print? Otherwise printing in the textbox is done under aaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbb. Can you show me in your answer please? Thank you

Comment: @JamesD.Com Can you simply remove the two lines from your code if they are not required?  Or add `text.delete("1.0", "end")` at the beginning of `Go()`.  Note that it will clear the text box whenever `Go()` is executed.

Comment: @acw1668 Ah okok. If it's not a nuisance, can I ask what ddddD is for master, **kw e super.? I've never used them. Thank you

Comment: Normally the *parent* of the widget should be passed when creating the widget, *master* is the parent of the widget.  `**kw` is the *keyword arguments*, for example `width=80, height=50, bg="black", fg="white"` passed to `Text(...)`.  For `super()`, please refer to the [`official document`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) for details.

Comment: @acw1668 Ah okok, thanks. I used your code, applied to my code, but there is something wrong. I entered the code in the question, in Upload 2. Scraping doesn't start in the Python console (it worked before), and nothing prints in the textobox. How can I solve? Thank you

Comment: You used `scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor()` within the `with` block, but later used `Scraping_Nome_Campionati.scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor()`.  So which one is correct?  Also why do you call the function twice?  Note that according to the supplied link, there are constraints: *"this context manager is not suitable for use in library code and most threaded applications. It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses."*  So it really depends on how `scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor()` is written.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a lot of trial and error I finally found a way to accomplish what You want (to be fair though, You were the one that was supposed to go through this phase AND show Your attempts which You failed to do, either how I don't mind much since I learned stuff too):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Text
import subprocess


def call_obj_from(obj, module):
    if module:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', f'from {module} import {obj}; {obj}()'],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        return proc.communicate()[0].decode()


root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.insert('end', call_obj_from('example_func_1', 'file.x'))
text.insert('end', call_obj_from('example_func_2', 'file.y'))

root.mainloop()
```

in simple terms the two arguments are `obj` or in other words what You will want to execute that also prints something to the console, and the `module` which is the file where that object is located so for example in this case I would have to have a file in the same directory named `functions.py` and in it there should be a function named `func()`

Comment: I thank you for your time and your kindness. I did not understand, however, where I have to write the name of the two py files, or in any case the name of their functions, that is, from File.X import Example_Name_Function_1, and then from File.Y import Example_Name_Function_2. Could you change your answer to these things please? Thank you

Comment: @JamesD.Com I added a simplified version of what You asked

Comment: Ah yes, it's all clearer now. Thank you. So there is no need to import the file at the beginning with from File.X import Example_Name_Function_1? You did it directly in the text.insert ('end', call_obj_from ('example_func_1', 'file.x')) line, did I understand correctly?

Comment: @JamesD.Com yep, no need to do that, I don't know how safe is this but I don't think that a user would be able to inject their own code so it should be fine, if the answer helped You, consider marking it as correct for future readers and so it is possible to use this in case of duplicates

Comment: I get an error, namely this: proc = subprocess.Popen (['python', '-c', f'from {module} import {obj}; {obj} () '], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
     self._execute_child (args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception_type (errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'

Comment: @JamesD.Com that is a bit weird, could You edit Your code and include the traceback and the code that caused the error in there?

Comment: My code is the same same code you wrote, but I only changed the path and filename to text.insert. Then it is the same as yours. But shouldn't I also use from subprocess import Popen, PIPE? However it says that the problem is the "python" file or path not found. My paths are File/X.py and File/Y.py

Comment: @JamesD.Com I already imported the whole subprocess moduel so no additional imports unless You really want are necessary. what I understand is that it doesn't know what python is, what OS are You using? maybe try changing `python` to `python3` or sth in that string in Popen

Comment: I use Linux. Yes, writing Python3 now I don't get errors, but there is a strange malfunction. Basically my app consists of clicking on the "Scraping" item in the horizontal bar of the menu bar and opening the window. The textobox is contained in that window. The functions need to be performed only when I click the "Start Scraping" button. In fact, it worked correctly. Now, however, if I click on the "Scraping" item, this window does NOT open, and the scraping starts, without me clicking on the "Start Scraping" button. After a few seconds, halfway through scraping, the window opens

Comment: Before entering your code, if I clicked on Scraping the window opened, but the scraping was not performed yet. It was only run after clicking on the Start Scraping button. I checked the typing spaces of the various defs and everything is ok. So it's your code that creates this problem. I hope I explained myself. I am writing with google translator.

Comment: @JamesD.Com I got what is happening, however it would be great if You provide the code for that part, edit it in Your post, because although I understand the issue, it is hard for me to imagine (although I have some ideas) what is causing the issue, so it would be great if You provided this code in Your question

Comment: Ok, I try, but be aware that the code is very long. It will take me a few minutes to edit it (to publicly adapt). Here with me it's late, if I don't make it in time then I'll publish it tomorrow. But I try to do now. I'll write another comment just made. Thanks again.

Comment: @JamesD.Com well, actually it is late for me too, so You could actually post it tomorrow, because I should get some sleep an if it is a long code, it will take a while to find the issue so ...

Comment: I updated the question by entering the code. I believe the problem is in the call_obj_from function you created. A problem related to the number of empty spaces in the rows and their order. When you answer, enter only the part where the problem is. Don't copy and paste my entire code please. Thank you

Comment: @JamesD.Com first of I don't see how You call `call_obj_from()` function. it is called in itself but not outside and actually why do You even call it in itself? if those two functions that You want the output from are the ones hat have those print statements then You should have another function that specifically calls my function with the parameters (obj and method) and then You could save the result to a variable (hence the return statement) and then insert that variable, like in Your given code there is no way anything even gets inserted to text except those two line of aaaa and bbbb

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. Pasting the code here into Stack Overflow is a little cumbersome. Sorry. Now I've put your function inside the def do_scraping function. In your code, however, you didn't write that you have to save the result in a variable (the return declaration). Can you edit your answer and show me how to please? (without copying all my code, just yours). Thank you

Comment: @JamesD.Com You don't necessarily need to save the returned value to a variable, You can easily return it directly to the `.insert()` method as I have shown in my example, the issue is that You have put those `.insert()` functions inside `call_obj_from()` function when in fact they should be somewhere outside, like as You said if You put this function inside the `def do_scraping()` function then probably somewhere at the end You need to call those insert methods with my function but this time so that they are inside the `do_scraping()` function, basically just change some indetation

Comment: also to be fair, if You don't understand the basics of how functions work in python then You should watch some tutorials because return is pretty basic stuff, You also apparently need to learn how variables work and stuff and also I have to say that nested function definitions are not the best practice and I would actually suggest to use a class, but You would have to learn the basics first